# Where can I find/join discussion on the scope of SO (on-topic/off-topic questions)?

Tags: support, policy

While I understand the merits of removing certain types of questions from SO (opinion-based questions, or questions generating discussion rather than straight answers, etc.), I also see downsides of this policy.

I'm sure that throughout the evolution of SO, the issue of what is and what is not on-topic on SO has been discussed extensively on Meta.  I would like to learn the arguments and insights of more experienced colleagues.  My questions:

1. Could someone point me to such discussions?  I'm interested both in historical debates and in current ones.
2. What mechanisms exist for changing the current policy?  Is it up to the creators? (probably not)  The mods?  Hypothetically, if the candidates that support more "inclusionist" stances were elected this time around, could they influence the scope?

Comment: #2 - post a feature request on meta.  For #1, which specific topics are you most interested in understanding?  There are probably dozens & dozens of relevant conversations

Comment: @psubsee2003 As for #1, I'm mostly worried about the "deletionist" mindset, to borrow [the term used in the Wikipedia community](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Deletionism), which affects borderline questions, [or even perfectly valid questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21435497/knuthmorrispratt-algorithm#comment32341970_21435497).  Such policy discourages and confuses users (which SE is good for my question?).  Instinctively, I would opt for a more "inclusionist" SO, a one stop shop for programmers. I would like to learn the arguments of both supporters and opponents of such view.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+was+my+question+closed+as+off+topic

Comment: @Won't Thanks, that sheds some light, but these are questions regarding specific closures.  I was looking for a more comprehensive discussion on the evolving scope of SO.

Comment: @Bolo: That convo is spread over hundreds and hundreds of questions over a span of four years.  Another place to look would be in the [meta-tag:faq] tag.  There might be links to relevant questions in relevant faq questions...

Comment: @Won't OK, I understand (I was wrongly assuming that the discussion was somehow centralized).  Would you like to write that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That conversation is not just one discussion; is spread over hundreds, maybe thousands, of questions over a span of four years.

You can skim the results of this search (I'd suggest going to the oldest and moving forward in time)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=why+was+my+question+closed+as+off+topic+is%3Aquestion

Another place to look would be in the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag. There might be links to relevant questions in faq questions about what is and is not an on topic question.